# Print some character repeatedly

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to print '.' 1000 times .

Like ......... 1000 times

Is there any query available, like this :

```
select '.'*1000 from dual;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LPAD/RPAD:

```
select lpad('.', 1000, '.') from dual ;
```